# The Ominous INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY Error on OrderItem Insert

Tags: apex, opportunity-lineitem, orderitem

So in an attempt to convert an `OpportunityLineItem` into an `OrderItem`, I get the mysterious and vague `INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY` Error on insert of an `OrderItem` list.

What's odd is my test class runs perfectly fine when doing the conversion. That's what is peculiar.

I will provide both the test code and the actual code to see if there are any gaps anywhere that I'm missing.

Here is some code to help convey what I am doing:

***Code to convert `OpportunityLineItem`***

```
public Map<Id, List<OrderItem>> ConvertOpportunityLineItemsToOrderItems(Set<Id> opportunityIdSet)
{
    if(opportunityIdSet == null || opportunityIdSet.size() == 0)
        return new Map<Id, List<OrderItem>>();

    Map<Id, List<OrderItem>> orderItems = new Map<Id, List<OrderItem>>();

    for(OpportunityLineItem lineItem : [SELECT PricebookEntryId, Quantity, UnitPrice, OpportunityId FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityId IN :opportunityIdSet])
    {
        if(orderItems.get(lineItem.OpportunityId) == null)
            orderItems.put(lineItem.OpportunityId, new List<OrderItem>());

        orderItems.get(lineItem.OpportunityId).add(new OrderItem(PricebookEntryId = lineItem.PricebookEntryId, Quantity = lineItem.Quantity, UnitPrice = lineItem.UnitPrice));
    }

    return orderItems;
}
```

***Test Utility code to generate `OpportunityLineItem` records***

```
public static List<OpportunityLineItem> CreateTestOpportunityLineItems(Integer numberOfRecords)
{
    sObject testOpportunity = TestsObjectGeneratorUtility.RetrieveGenerator(Opportunity.sObjectType).GenerateTestsObjects(1, true)[0];
    List<sObject> testProducts = TestsObjectGeneratorUtility.RetrieveGenerator(Product2.sObjectType).GenerateTestsObjects(numberOfRecords, true);

    List<PricebookEntry> testEntries = new List<PricebookEntry>();

    for(sObject testProduct : testProducts)
        testEntries.add(new PricebookEntry(Pricebook2Id = Test.getStandardPricebookId(), Product2Id = testProduct.Id, UnitPrice = 9001, IsActive = true));
    INSERT testEntries;

    List<OpportunityLineItem> lineItems = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
    for(sObject testEntry : testEntries)    
        lineItems.add(new OpportunityLineItem(Discount = 0, PricebookEntryId = testEntry.Id, Quantity = 1, UnitPrice = 500, OpportunityId = testOpportunity.Id));
    INSERT lineItems;
    return lineItems;   
}
```

***Code in Test method***

> This code runs to completion without an Exceptions.

```
TestUtilities.CreateTestOpportunityLineItems(3);
Opportunity testOpportunity = [SELECT Id FROM Opportunity LIMIT 1]; 

//Convert OpportunityLineItems
List<OrderItem> orderItems = (new OrderService()).ConvertOpportunityLineItemsToOrderItems(opportunityLineItemIds).get(testOpportunity.Id);

//Convert Opportunity to Order
Order testOrder = (new OrderService()).ConvertOpportunitiesToOrders(new Set<Id>{ testOpportunity.Id })[0];
INSERT testOrder;

for(OrderItem singleItem : orderItems)
    singleItem.OrderId = testOrder.Id;
INSERT orderItems;
```

***Code in Anonymous Apex***

> This code fails with `INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY` error

```
Id testingId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

Order newOrder = (new OrderService()).ConvertOpportunitiesToOrders(new Set<Id>{ testingId })[0];
INSERT newOrder;

List<OrderItem> orderItems = (new OrderService()).ConvertOpportunityLineItemsToOrderItems(new Set<Id>{ testingId }).get(testingId);
for(OrderItem singleItem : orderItems)
    singleItem.OrderId = newOrder.Id;
INSERT orderItems;
```

Here are some other notes:

- As far as I can tell, the `OpportunityLineItem` does have entries in the Standard `Pricebook`
- The `OpportunityLineItem` is available to be queried (otherwise, it wouldn't fail at all
- The `PricebookEntryId` is available

I am at my wits end on this one. The error doesn't help at all in troubleshooting and this is the last feature I need to implement... Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: 1) as an aside `ConvertOpportunityLineItemsToOrderItems` should return an empty list if the input id set is null or empty. 2) Your logic in this class is problematic in other ways -- if the size of the `opportunityidSet` is > 1, the caller has no way of knowing which line items belong to which order parent to assign the orderId into the OrderItem collection

Comment: 3) Note also that anon Apex runs at V33 (current version) whereas classes run at their metadata level

Comment: Thank you for the tips @crop1645. I will definitely add that logic to my method. Those asides are extremely helpful. That's what happens when you rush a Proof of Concept, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out what it was. Apparently, there was two Pricebooks. Once was call Standard and one was the Standard Pricebook. I actually set the Pricebook2Id on the order to the **standard pricebook** instead of the pricebook called **Standard**. Once I found that out, the rest was rather easy. Confusing, but none the less, informative.